# Verify XML digital signature

Tags: rsa, public-key, signature, xml-encryption

I'm trying to figure out how to verify an XML digital signature.

I have received a signed XML response (in string) in following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
   <HEADER>
      <tag1 />
   </HEADER>
   <Body />
   <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <SignedInfo>
         <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
         <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
         <Reference URI="">
            <Transforms>
               <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>hTKE4DcevU+1LWf78hwVjGJvjwA=</DigestValue>
         </Reference>
      </SignedInfo>
      <SignatureValue>tmuTneoW6tHNAv13Z2mybXx/8M+AfF8Qa44DUFZEVk2kdztUiEjk589WJVDecEBsRA2tTQEBhKol/5Bv8bS9Nc1XrS8gKF5vjj14vnFKpSpsNvyooKfv3w50jrOaZeYd5PXWTxB4BT9wL8ogU51/plT6T8A8EdMoLw5zOPO6noTLdi2tAGF3OzLQla+BOtlrxliCfwWkWisBOwWO0kpgsQjxqx2dIS69JHuz5V/aj3tCXLzr2lX9P/S+urn6NU1YEHlVYYs+fFXnKCeHtBhwnz7hDLEB2bovW0rfft3bSNkvylrOfuGbAhRE/ey8g4M3pA5wpufu3eqZv0s4e1uYag==</SignatureValue>
   </Signature>
</ROOT>
```

I have the RSA public key of the sender in `.pem` format and the digital certificate in `.cer` format. This is what I've tried till now to verify the signature by reading various resources online:

- Converted the `<SignedInfo>` root element into canonical format
- Computed the SHA1 digest of the canonicalised XML
- Encrypted the digest with the public key available with me as mentioned above
- Compare the encrypted value with the value present in `<SignatureValue>` element in the above XML

However, the two values do not match. Does this mean that the verification has failed? Or am I doing something wrong? (I have a feeling the latter is true)